# Method for estimating a constant in curve fitting

Tags: optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I will be given two arrays with the same length. [An example is here.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Sz9YkfoL8xmO-E8Pna0cjMFnajf7FRmk?usp=sharing) In the example, the time array is for x-axis and the intensity array is for y-axis. I am asked to fit the graph with slightly altered lognormal probability density function (the domain is $t>0$):

(I really don't know how to LaTeX in stackoverflow)

```
\begin{equation*}
f(t) = \frac{a}{\sigma t\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(\frac{-(\ln(t)-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}) + b
\end{equation*}
```

In other words, if the graph of the two arrays looks like:[image]

I want to determine the fitting constants $a$, $b$, $\sigma$, and $m$ such that $f(t)$ looks something like:

[image]

My plan is to use the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. More precisely:

```
intensity = np.load('intensity.npy')
time = np.load('time.npy')

def func(t, a, b, m, s): #s=sigma and n = m, just to recopy my formula for f
    t = np.array(t)
    return b + a*np.exp((-1)*(np.log((t))-n)**2/(2*s**2)) / (t)*s*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)

initial = #something to work out
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, time, intensity,initial)
plt.plot(time, func(time, *popt), linewidth=0.6, color = 'black')
plt.plot(time,intensity,linewidth=0.1, color = 'black')
plt.xlabel("Time(Seconds)")
plt.ylabel("Average Intensity")
plt.savefig('result.png', dpi = 1200)
```

The method does not work well if initial estimate is not given. However, the problem here is that the arrays intensity and time are given to me. I have no control on the initial estimate and hence need a mathematical way to get a general estimation on the fitting constants. This is where I get stuck as I am really not familiar with the lognormal distribution. Is there any method that helps me quickly an estimation of constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not a scipy or a Python question, and is perhaps better suited for the sister site https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

However here is my proposed solution for coming up with good initial values. It does rely on the knowledge of the lognormal distribution as in for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

The curve you are trying to fit is a shifted (by `b`) and scaled (by `a`) log-normal probability density. First we want to estimate these. As the log-normal density takes values in $[0,+infty)$, the initial estimate for parameter `b` coiuld be set to the lowest value of the `intensity`. Also, the integral of the log-normal density should be 1 for definition, hence `a` should be set to the integral of `intensity` shifted by `b`. After that we have a (true) lognormal density in `intensity` and we can estimate `m` and `s` from the mean of the distribution and its variance (in fact we just use the second moment). This logic is implemented in the function `get_initial_values` below. I also modify your `func` to make sure `t` is always strictly positive as otherwise it messes log, leads to division by zero, etc. Also it had a type `n` vs `m`.  Here is the full code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def func(t, a, b, m, s): #s=sigma and n = m, just to recopy my formula for f
    t = np.array(t)
    t = np.maximum(t,1e-4) # guard against zeros or negative values
    return b + a*np.exp((-1)*(np.log(t)-m)**2/(2*s**2)) / (t)*s*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)

def get_initial_values(t,x):
    min_x = np.min(x)
    integral_x = np.sum((x[:-1] - min_x)*np.diff(t))
    
    a = integral_x
    b = min_x
    normalized_x = (x - b)/a

    mean_t = np.sum((normalized_x[:-1] *t[:-1] )*np.diff(t))
    mean_t2 = np.sum((normalized_x[:-1] *t[:-1]**2 )*np.diff(t))
    

    s = np.sqrt(np.log(mean_t2) - 2*np.log(mean_t))
    m = np.log(mean_t) - s*s/2

    return np.array([a,b,m,s])

initial = get_initial_values(time, intensity)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, time, intensity,initial)
```

The result for your data is plotted here:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works.